# Can the Google Sleep Tracking API be technically used for IPhone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, sleep

I'm wondering if the the Sleep Tracking API that Google released for Android can also be used (or reserve-engineered or repackaged) to be used for iPhone devices? (for building a sleep tracking application)

It says the API is powered by Google Play Services (not sure what that means)

https://developers.google.com/location-context/sleep
https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/main/SleepSampleKotlin

Thanks
Gabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Google play services is an Android library that provides functionality above what the base OS does and integrates with Google services.  While its possible for Google to build it for another OS, they generally don't provide libraries like this for iOS, except for some of their paid services like maps.